# dropdown by clicking on icon on the image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need an ellipsis icon in top right corner of an image. which shows options like dropdown menu when we click on it. The dropdown menu should be in the boundary of image.

The should look like the one in chrome just like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXiJ3.png)

here is my code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk6nL0az/)

```css
.portfolio-item {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 32.04%;
    /*width: 25%;*/
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
 /*height: 300px;*/
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 12px 12px 0;
}
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;

}
.top-left a{
    color: white;
    /*display: inline;*/
    /*background-color: black;*/
    /*font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;


}
.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
/* Bottom left text */
.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 10px;
}
.bottom-left a{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    /*display: inline;*/
    /*background-color: black;*/
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head><article class="portfolio-item pf-grading pf-asset-management">
   <div class="portfolio-image">
   <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fly-jamaica.com/charters/charter-request-form/400x300.gif/@@images/image.gif" alt="Open Imagination"></a>
<div class="top-left"><a href="#">Any Text here</a></div>
 <a href="#"><div class="top-right"><i class="icon-line-ellipsis"></i></div></a>
  </div>
  </article>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to explain to us what specific problem you are facing. This is not a code-writing service, we don’t work on the basis of a mere “I want”.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c04qe1op/)  same as below
Updated the same code, Might be useful.
Positioning is completely upto you

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style>
        .btn {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 12px 24px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 5px;
            }
    </style>
</head><article class="portfolio-item pf-grading pf-asset-management">
   <div class="portfolio-image">
   <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Btn
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
   <img src="https://www.fly-jamaica.com/charters/charter-request-form/400x300.gif/@@images/image.gif" alt="Open Imagination">
 <a href="#"><div class="top-right"><i class="icon-line-ellipsis"></i></div></a>
  </div>
  </article>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```